# How to do not freeze wpf app on closing event

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF app and I want to execute some method in the `Closing` event. It can take several minutes, that's why the WPF window freezes. Here is my code:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Closing += MainWindow_Closing;
    }

    void MainWindow_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Run(new Action(ClaseAfterThreeSecond)).Wait();
    }

    void ClaseAfterThreeSecond()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
    }
```

I want to do not freeze the WPF app until `MainWindow_Closing` ends when I click the X button (close button) on the WPF app. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**
This way closes the window immediately. I don't need this:

```
  async void MainWindow_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Run(new Action(ClaseAfterThreeSecond));
    }
```

Comment: Make event handler async and await call to  Task.Run inside it?

Comment: @balbelias, I tried, it closes the window immediately. I need to close the window after completing MainWindow_Closing method

Comment: And what about that way: `await Task.Run(new Action(ClaseAfterThreeSecond)).CondigureAwait(false);`. Also get rid of `Thread.Sleep` in `ClaseAfterThreeSecond` and change it to `Task.Delay`.

Comment: @balbelias It didn't work. Window closes immediately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make your handler `async`, but as it `async void` it returns right after your first `await` call. Just cancel original closing event and close directly in your code:

```
private async void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    // cancel original closing event
    e.Cancel = true;

    await CloseAfterThreeSeconds();
}

private async Task CloseAfterThreeSeconds()
{
    // long-running stuff...
    await Task.Delay(3000);

    // shutdown application directly
    Application.Current.Shutdown();
}
```